# Does $ P(X=x|W=\tilde{w}, P(Y=y|W=w)=a) $ make sense?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have the following question. Consider a discrete random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathcal{X}\subset \mathbb{R}$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

Consider other two discrete random variables $Y:\Omega\rightarrow \mathcal{Y}\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $W:\Omega\rightarrow \mathcal{W}\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that there is some additional process in the model such that $P(Y=y|W=w)$ is a random variable itself for $y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $w\in \mathcal{W}$ with support $\{a,b\}\subset [0,1]$.

I am wondering whether the conditioning event of the following conditional probability has probability zero
$$
P(X=x|W=\tilde{w}, P(Y=y|W=w)=a)
$$
for $w\neq \tilde{w}$ and $x\in \mathcal{X}$. Can you provide some formal argument?

Comment: The probability $P(Y=y\mid W=w)$ can be equal to $0$ i.e. $a=0$ but that is no problem.

Comment: Thanks. My confusion derives from the fact that I am conditioning on $\tilde{w}$ and, then, inside the conditional probability I have $w$. As you suggested, this shouldn't be a problem but I don't know how to formally explain it.

Comment: In your setting, $P(Y=y|W=w)$ is a number, not a random variable, hence the expression $P(X=x|W=\tilde{w}, P(Y=y|W=w)=a)$ is meaningless. Please explain how $P(Y=y|W=w)=P(Y=y,W=w)/P(W=w)$ can be a random variable.

Comment: @Did I can't write down a structural model here.